# Does VirtualEnv really work for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

Recently my OS (Arch Linux) updated Python from 3.5.2 to 3.6, after that I had [a little problem with VirtualEnvWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639848/virtualenvwrapper-does-not-initialize-after-updating-python-to-3-6), it's solved now. I wished to try my existing virtual enviroment that was created with Python 3.5.2, but...

```
$ workon default_env
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0
$ deactivate
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0
```

Something is really wrong here, because output should be Python 3.5.2 and not Python 3.6. In or out of my virtual environment if I run this:

```
$ pip list
```

I get the same packages listed. Where are my packages installed for my virtual environment (VE)? For example, If I try run *ipython* from my VE I get this:

```
$ ipython
bash: /home/user/.envs/default_env/bin/ipython: /home/user/.envs/default_env/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/python-determine-if-running-inside-virtualenv), but it's not useful.

Comment: You can check if your using the python from you virtualenv after your `workon default_env` by doing a `whereis python`, check if it is your virtual_env. If not, recreate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506110/is-it-possible-to-install-another-version-of-python-to-virtualenv) I looked into [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) and [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv), and with the help of [this great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lw-irZyZmcc), I found a tool quite similar to Ruby's RVM, I love it because it won't any problems with future updates from system. Right, there is another tool like [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/index.html), but I like more **pyenv**.